# Assign a single array value to different sections in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a array (resultArray) which has 21 items of data in it. I want to display it in a 8 sectioned table with different row counts.

How to assign the value properly in all row? Both indexpath.row and section.row gives wrong values. How to assign a single array value to grouped table with more section?

Comment: Please provide more specific details that how you decide how many rows in perticular section and how will it change..

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you to map your data model to the table view, and you can do it any way that you want. If you have a flat array of items and want to map them into different sections of the table view, you'll have to know which offsets of the result data go into which sections of the table, but no one can do that for you automatically, because only you know the semantics of the data. You need some code that takes the section and row index and figures out which index into the results array needs to be returned.

If it's always 21 items and always the same mapping, then hardcoding the mapping in a table or a big bunch of `if` statements is probably fine. If it's dynamic then you'd need some other lookaside mapping table, depending on how you wanted to map.

Finally, as @iPortable suggests, you could also find a way to structure your results data appropriately, which makes the controller logic simple, depending on your data.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a multi layer array for this. The first level would be the section count and the second level the row. The array would look something like this:

```
resultArray{
    1 = {
        1 = first row in first section,
        2 = second row in first section
    },
    2 = {
        1 = first row in second section,
        2 = second row in second section
    }
}
```

then you get the value from the array in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *sectionArray = [returnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```